# Is one allowed to make Kneidlach when the last day of Pesach is Shabbos?

Tags: minhag, calendar, matzah, gebrochts

**According to those who eat Gebrotz only on the last day of Pesach**, is one allowed to make Mazta balls when the last day of Pesach is Shabbos?

On a normal year, one can cook and eat Gebrotz on the last day, however, when the last day of Pesach falls out on Shabbos, can one cook Gebrotz on Friday?

Comment: Do people who don't eat gebrochts also not own gebrochts, or is it like kitniyot where owning it is permitted? Or is that really your question? If so maybe you can generalize the text.

Comment: Wouldn't it be covered by the Eruv Tavshilin, like everything else?

Comment: @Alex That's assuming you think you're allowed to own it.

Comment: @Alex: Doesn't there have to be a possibility for the food cooked on yom tov to be eaten on yom tov (before shabbat starts - http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2327/jewish/Eruv-Tavshilin.htm) If one doesn't eat the matza balls on the 7th day, wouldn't this mean that it is not covered by the Eruv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Otzar Minhagei Chabad](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30483&st=&pgnum=236), which in turn quotes from R' Leibel Groner (the Lubavitcher Rebbe's personal secretary):

[image]

The context here is discussing the fact that while throughout [pesach](/questions/tagged/pesach) Chabad does *not* eat [gebrochts](/questions/tagged/gebrochts) (matza shruyah), on the eighth and last day of Pesach, they make a point to davka eat it.

Quick translation:

> When the last day of Pesach falls on Shabbos, there are those that have the custom to make "kneidlach" (matza balls) on the *7th* day [whereas it would normally be made only on the eighth], obviously with special dishes, that are specifically set aside for this.
>
> And so writes R' Leibel Groner about the custom of the Lubavitcher Rebbe z"iya:
>
> > "I remember that one year [when the last day of Pesach was Shabbos] it was not prepared [the "kneidlach"]. On the eighth night, when it wasn't brought to the table, the Rebbe asked the reason for it. It was answered that it was thought that when the last day of Pesach is Shabbos it wasn't appropriate to cook this. And the Rebbe was not pleased with this at all."

---

The sefer goes on to quote from several different tzaddikim that had the same custom.

Comment: Why the tag links?

Comment: @DoubleAA I tagged gebrochts because I wanted to make sure anyone who didn't know what it was would find out. I tagged Pesach for no reason at all.

Answer (score 9):

Per the [Nitei Gavriel Pesach Volume 3 Chapter 19:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46449&st=&pgnum=120) one may prepare them on Sheviyi Shel Pesach so long they made an Eruv Tavshilin.

Answer (score 8):

According to the Bedatz of Crown Heights,

> It is told that the [Lubavitcher] Rebbe's household was accustomed to to eat gebrochts in the form of kneidlach on the final day of Pesach - regardless of whether the final day coincided with Shabbos. Naturally such foods can be prepared only if one had made an Eiruv Tavshilin.

---

[image: image source of above text]

Comment: You're really getting mileage out of this image.